# Tailwind and React bootstrap Padding Issue

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, styling

i am a new developer using react bootstrap, Tailwind CSS, React Router and Vite. I am having a padding issue i believe where the styling is conflicting. Before i used React router to display my components containing Bootstrap forms my navbar slid in and out of the left part of the screen and the icons were still visible, now they disappear when expanded towards the form.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router";
import Example_function from "./Workouts-page";
import Example_function2 from "./SingleWorkout-page";
import Example_function3 from "./Registration-page";
import Example_function4 from "./Nutrition-page";
import Example_function5 from "./Login-Page";
import Example_function6 from "./Home-page";
import Example_function7 from "./Exercise-page";
import Example_function8 from "./Coaches-page";

const Nav = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const Menus = [//This is images and titles
    {title: "Dashboard", src: "home1"},
    {title: "Inbox", src: "messages2"},
    {title: "Accounts", src: "user1", gap:true},
    {title: "Schedule", src: "calendar2"},
    {title: "Search", src: "search"},
    {title: "Analytics", src: "analytics"},
    {title: "Files", src: "folder1", gap : true},
    {title: "Settings", src: "setting"},
  ];
//STYLING below
  return (
    <div className=" flex">
      <div
        className={` ${
          open ? " h-auto w-72 " : "w-20 "
        } bg-slate-500 h-screen p-5  pt-8 relative duration-300`}
      >
        <img
          src="./src/Assets/mastercontrol.png"
          className={`absolute cursor-pointer -right-3 top-9 w-7 border-dark-purple
           border-2 rounded-full  ${!open && "rotate-180"}`}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div className="flex gap-x-4 items-center">
          <img
            src="./src/Assets/icons8-dumbbell-50.png"
            className={`cursor-pointer duration-500 ${
              open && "rotate-[360deg]"
            }`}
          />
          <h1
            className={`text-white origin-left font-medium text-xl duration-200 ${
              !open && "scale-0"
            }`}
          >
            Designer
          </h1>
        </div>
        <ul className="pt-6">
          {Menus.map((Menu, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              className={`flex  rounded-md p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-light-white text-gray-300 text-sm items-center gap-x-4 
              ${Menu.gap ? "mt-9" : "mt-2"} ${
                index === 0 && "bg-light-white"
              } `}
            >
              <img src={`./src/Assets/${Menu.src}.png`} />
              <span className={`${!open && "hidden"} origin-left duration-200`}>
                {Menu.title}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="h-screen flex p-10">
       
       <Routes>
        <Route path="/"element={<Example_function6/>} />
        <Route path="/coaches"element={<Example_function8/>} />
        <Route path="/Nutrition"element={<Example_function4/>} />
        <Route path="/Registration"element={<Example_function3/>} />
        <Route path="/Login-page"element={<Example_function5/>} />
        <Route path="/Single-Workouts-page"element={<Example_function2/>} />
        <Route path="/Workouts-page"element={<Example_function/>} />
        <Route path="/Exercise-page"element={<Example_function7/>} />
      </Routes> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  //ROUTES go here 
};
export default Nav;
```

//This is the bootstrap Component

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
const Example_function3= () =>{
    return(
     
    <Form>
      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
        <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="1234 Main St" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
        <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
          <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select defaultValue="Choose...">
            <option>Choose...</option>
            <option>...</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
          <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control />
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>

      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>

  );
}
export default Example_function3
```

Youtube, Senior Developer stack overflow